# Emulator is not working on android studio latest version Hedgehog

Tags: linux, android-studio, android-emulator

When I start a virtual device it show's me a popup which says starting AVD but as it reaches 50/60% the popup disappears and noting happens. I am providing all the details let me know if you need anything else.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That OS looks like Linux. What distribution and version? What display system is used? Have you checked the log file(s) in the age directory? AFIR in the context menu of they've there is an option to erase the current state (RAM that has been saved to disk to speed-up Start-up). Have you tried that function?